# Arrange output vertically and side-by-side in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list

So I want to arrange arithmetic problems vertically in a nice column.

Code:
`def arithmetic_arranger(problems, calculate = False):

```
for problem in problems:
    problem = problem.split()
    first_number = problem[0]
    second_number = problem[2]
    sign = problem[1]
    
    try:
        first_number = int(first_number) 
        second_number = int(second_number)   
    except:
        print('Error: Numbers must only contain digits.')
        break

    if calculate is True:
        if sign == '+':
            result = first_number + second_number
        else:
            result = first_number - second_number

    print(f'{first_number}\n{sign} {second_number}\n-----')
    
    if calculate is True:
        print(result)
```

arithmetic_arranger(["32 + 8", "1 - 3801", "9999 + 9999", "523 - 49"], True)`

This is the current output:

```
+ 8
-----
40
1
- 3801
-----
-3800
9999
+ 9999
-----
19998
523
- 49
-----
474
```

And I want to turn that into:

```
  32         1      9999      523
+  8    - 3801    + 9999    -  49
----    ------    ------    -----
  40     -3800     19998      474
```

I have tried adding first numbers to list and then displaying them in the row but that didn't really work.

Comment: You can't do this in one pass. When you iterate over the problems, you need to build up the first operands, the operators, the second operands, and the results. You then display each of those in a row, after determining the spacing necessary according to the width of the widest field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a proposition (*based on your code*) with a little help from [tabulate](/questions/tagged/tabulate).

```
#pip install tabulate
from tabulate import tabulate
​
def arithmetic_arranger(problems, calculate=False):
    problem_lists = [problem.split() for problem in problems]
    
    if calculate:
        results = [eval(" ".join(problem)) for problem in problem_lists]
        problem_lists = [problem_lists[i] + [result]
                         for i, result in enumerate(results)]
        
    problem_lists = list(map(list, zip(*problem_lists)))
    problem_lists[1:3] = [[" ".join(x)
                           for x in zip(problem_lists[1], problem_lists[2])]]
​
    print(tabulate(problem_lists, tablefmt="simple", showindex=False, 
                   numalign="right", stralign="right"))
```

Output :
​

```
arithmetic_arranger(["32 + 8", "1 - 3801", "9999 + 9999", "523 - 49"], True)
​
---  ------  ------  ----
 32       1    9999   523
+ 8  - 3801  + 9999  - 49
 40   -3800   19998   474
---  ------  ------  ----
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd approach this by creating a function that takes the two numbers to add/subtract as numbers, not strings. Then using `len(str(x))` to infer the printed length of the number as a string, we can print the appropraite number of leading spaces and dashes.

```py
def long_op(x, y, op="+"):
    if op == "+":
        result = x + y
    elif op == "-":
        result = x - y
    else:
        raise ValueError("op must be + or -")
    width = max([len(str(i)) for i in [x, y]])
    first = " " * (2 + width - len(str(x))) + str(x)
    second = op + " " * (1 + width - len(str(y))) + str(y)
    bar = "-" * (2 + width)
    last = " " * (2 + width - len(str(result))) + str(result)
    return "\n".join([first, second, bar, last])

def multi_ops(*args):
    long_ops = [long_op(*arg).split("\n") for arg in args]
    transpose = list(map(list, zip(*long_ops)))
    return "\n".join(["   ".join(l) for l in transpose])

print(long_op(32,8))
print()
print(multi_ops([32,8], [1,3801,"-"], [9999,9999], [523,49,"-"]))
```

Output:

```
  32
+  8
----
  40

  32        1     9999     523
+  8   - 3801   + 9999   -  49
----   ------   ------   -----
  40    -3800    19998     474
```

Demo at [SageCell.SageMath.org](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJyFUt1qgzAUvi_0HQ5eJTWWtd2gHXi5V9iNk5HO2GXEKElkuqffiYl1g5VFkJPj93N-rEQNqtWX17YjA4ORQdvlSZrQx_UK8MgaE5DngLmY8scI2ysHOQyQwhjyQi3g7AY4W8BW_IRwaQU8c9WLJ2NaQxIUanrr4CzQoTWQJTTAP2Xl3lGs4QMplNDEOkMkpVAjSoLUUPhGyjLia2msN0_w2QDZo1yQyGBmDxTpKYQwsKx4a3WFNKwjnbm7P7jjwh0j98wNTDP45Rc_Kv5fNWFci2y8B7oRrjcakhedbD9aqUkx9cdiwcybs8nE979eVbjfBukSF2zJhpuLnVcb126xmmL-BTyAbm2npCPeI0wVk36unlwGrjNc267FneWgpHWk4R3xAYMviTKzNnZxq-4EszFWwUZ5k6tyqL8zUjsyl3fYs6NXDNlrsDRYeETJoNixw_Fux3AJ_nbCw_zLXx72B3Z_mj5R-g0Z5dQE&lang=python&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==).